# Directory not changing -java gui

Tags: java

So , here I am trying to simulate filemanager using java gui.
The textfield displays the current directory and also we can change directory  by editing it and clicking button "go".
My problem is the directory is not changing i.e it doesnt show any changes below it.
Thanks in Advance.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cp7To.png)

Code is

```
 import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Date;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class Try extends JFrame{
    JPanel centerp,topp,downp; 
    JTextField addr;
    JButton go;
    int h,w;
     public Try(){
      setLayout(new BorderLayout());
      centerp= new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
      topp=new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
      addr=new JTextField(50);
      go=new JButton("GO");

    File dir;
    dir = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir"));
    addr.setText(dir.getAbsolutePath());
    topp.add(addr,BorderLayout.WEST);

    go.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                    try {
                       String a = addr.getText();
                       System.setProperty("user.dir", a);

                    } catch(Exception t) {
                       System.out.println("error");
                    }

                }});
   topp.add(go);

    FileTableModl model = new FileTableModl(dir);

      JTable table = new JTable(model);
      centerp= new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
       centerp.add(new JScrollPane(table) );
       add(topp,BorderLayout.NORTH);
       add(centerp,BorderLayout.CENTER);
  }
}

class FileTableModl extends AbstractTableModel {
  protected File dir;
  protected String[] filenames;

  protected String[] columnNames = new String[] {
    "name", "size", "last modified"  };

  protected Class[] columnClasses = new Class[] { 
    String.class, Long.class, Date.class  };

    public FileTableModl(File dir) { 
    this.dir = dir; 
    this.filenames = dir.list();  
  }


  public int getColumnCount() { return 3; } 
  public int getRowCount() { return filenames.length; }  


  public String getColumnName(int col) { return columnNames[col]; }
 public Class getColumnClass(int col) { return columnClasses[col]; }

   public Object getValueAt(int row, int col) {
    File f = new File(dir, filenames[row]);
    switch(col) {
    case 0: return filenames[row];
    case 1: return new Long(f.length());
    case 2: return new Date(f.lastModified());
    default: return null;
    }

  }
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
      Try gui=new Try();
    gui.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
       gui.pack();
        gui.setVisible(true);
    gui.setTitle("Try");
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Calling `System.setProperty("user.dir", a);` is going to have no affect whatsoever on your UI. You need to tell the UI that something has changed. Maybe something like this:

```
go.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
    {
        try {
            File candidate = new File(addr.getText());
            if (candidate.exists() && candidate.isDirectory()) {
                table.setModel(new FileTableModl(candidate));
            }
        } catch (Exception t) {
            t.printStackTrace(System.err);
        }
    }
});
```

For this to work, you need to make `table` (a `JTable`) a member field and not a variable local to the `Try` constructor.